# Как сделать jquery код неконфликтным

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мои подключения jquery добавляются ниже всех. Но выше могут еще быть скрипты jquery, как можно сделать 100% неконфликтными мои скрипты? Пробовал так:

```
 <script src="/js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script><script src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

И вначало main.js добавлял var `$j = $.noConflict();` но в итоге мне выдовало ошибку на 1 строчке, ***$ is not defined***  хотя скрипт подключен выше. Как можно сделать скрипт неконфликтным в данном случае? Ведь он по идее ниже всех

Comment: Посмотрите Network-панель, у вас точно загружается /js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js ?

Comment: @ZhukovRoman , да

Comment: может проще проверять, есть ли уже jquery и если нет - то подгружать свой?

Comment: @xaja ,  в таком случае изначальный jquery может быть старый, и код соответственно ниже моего jquery не функциональный

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
<script>$.noConflict();</script>
```